# Javascript RegExp returning unwanted characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got this string:

```
<AdParameters>
    <VpaidClickThrough><![CDATA[http://media.adrcdn.com/ads/exit.html]]></VpaidClickThrough>
    <VpaidClickTracking><![CDATA[]]></VpaidClickTracking> 
    <VpaidPath><![CDATA[http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.adrcdn.com%2Fads%2FAdrime%2F3130343734%2F61112%2F]]></VpaidPath> 
    <VpaidDuration><![CDATA[]]></VpaidDuration>
    <VpaidId><![CDATA[e322f52bc813f05beacb6fe522a52f20]]></VpaidId>
</AdParameters>
<MediaFiles>
    <MediaFile id="0" maintainAspectRatio="false" scalable="false" delivery="progressive"  width="640" height="360" apiFramework='VPAID' type="application/x-shockwave-flash">  <![CDATA[http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.adrcdn.com%2Fads%2FAdrime%2F3130343734%2F61112%2Fmediafile_lineair_640x360.swf?VpaidId=e322f52bc813f05beacb6fe522a52f20&VpaidPath=http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.adrcdn.com%2Fads%2FAdrime%2F3130343734%2F61112%2F]]></MediaFile>
<MediaFiles>
```

And I want to extract from here all the ENCODED URLs.
So I'm using this RegExp:

```
(http\%3A.*)\?|(http\%3A.*)\]\]
```

But what I get is this:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.adrcdn.com%2Fads%2FAdrime%2F3130343734%2F61112%2F]]
http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.adrcdn.com%2Fads%2FAdrime%2F3130343734%2F61112%2Fmediafile_lineair_640x360.swf?
http%3A%2F%2Fmedia.adrcdn.com%2Fads%2FAdrime%2F3130343734%2F61112%2F]]
```

It's quite ok but I don't want the final "]]" and "?"
How do I get the URLs without those ending characters?

It's strange because trying my regex here http://regex101.com/r/zS0tZ8 it looks to work perfectly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why did u put \\]\\] in your regex then?

Comment: You're misreading the match on that page. The section under Math Groups lists only the parts of your regex that were captured i.e. in parentheses. If you look at the actual string, you will see that they are actually matching the extra characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regex101 I believe you are considering the captured group, but that's not all the regex returns: the *match* itself will be what's matched by the *whole* regex, not only what's inside parenthesis.

This basically means you've got to ways of solving your issue:

- **return the first captured group**. Your regex does the job alright, you just need to return the correct captured value. (BTW, no need to escape `]]`. You can factorize it with `(http%3A.*?)(?:\?|]])`, the `(?: )` being a non-capturing group)
- edit your regex so that the end delimiter **isn't part of the match**. Something with look ahead could work, like `http%3A.*?(?=\?|]])` (notice there's no need for parenthesis anymore), but you could probably achieve the same thing with:

  ```
  http%3A[^]?]*
  ```

  The `[^ ]` meaning "anything but what's inside the brackets".

Comment: No need to escape `%` here! ;)

Comment: @KendallFrey: woop you're right, I just copied it right in. :/ Thanks!

Comment: I tried all your suggestions in here http://www.regextester.com/ and the only one that returned what I wanted is the look-ahead one. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Seems that you need to escape like so: `[^\]?]` in regextester, but this isn't normal behavior... FYI I usually use [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) for simple regex, and [regex101](htt://regex101.com) for more complicated ones (lookbehinds, captured groups...). The `http%3A[^]?]*` solution works in both :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions to this, but this is what I prefer:

```
http%3A[\w%.]*
```

This just matches what's in a valid encoded URL, without worrying about what comes afterward.

Answer (score 0):

```
http%3A.*?(?=\?|]])
```

should do the job

EDIT: little explanation:

```
(?=regex)
```

...tests the regex without adding the results to the match. It's called "positive lookahead".

Comment: No need to escape `]]` here!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you used your RegExp, but this should work:

```
function extractEncodedURLs(str) {
  var pattern = /(http%3A.*?)(\?|]])/g;

  var results = [];
  var match;
  while (match = pattern.exec(str)) {
    results.push(match[1]);
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: FYI no need to escape the `]]`, nor the `%`!